# How can you solve for acceleration and time that a vehicle takes to stop given only the speed, distance, and crumple length?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Here is the problem: A car initially has a speed of 115km/h. Find its acceleration and the time taken to stop given that: (a) it brakes to a stop in 64.0 m; (b) it crashes head-on into a barrier and crumples by 1.00 m.

I know that acceleration is the derivative of the velocity function but I don't know how to solve for that if I don't have time. Similarly for time, I can't solve it since I don't have acceleration. Am I missing something key in this problem?

Comment: Do you have the formulas $v^2 = 2as$ and $s=\frac{1}{2} at^2$ ?

Comment: Try the kinematic equation $v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2a\Delta x$.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the time it takes to stop knowing that $$ \int v dt = x $$ so you know that it takes 64 $m$ to completely stop and so you have $$ \int_{v_0}^{0} v(t) dt = 64, $$ where $v_0$ is $115 km/h$ in $m/s$. Since I assume the acceleration is constant, the above is equivalent to $$ (v_0 - 0) t = 64, $$ there you have the time and you should be able to solve the problem.